# Are there any security concerns with storing private keys in browser's javascript?

Tags: encryption, javascript

I'm working on a web app, and I know little about security/cryptography (for now, still learning) but I'm trying to set up a front-end where:

At the very beginning, the user puts in their private key.

The key is stored as a variable in javascript.

Any time the user does anything to interact with the backend, the key is used to sign or encrypt whatever data it needs to, the data is sent, and when the user is done with everything, they close the browser.

Is this a secure way of doing this? Can anything but my JS code access this key in the process?

(P.S. it's gonna be RSA or ECC so asymmetric, private key is only known by front end user)

Comment: Why the extra signing with the key?  Is regular HTTPS not good enough?  If the idea is to make it so that _you_ can prove that the client affirmatively did something, this would be disqualified on the grounds that the client has now given you (access to) their key, and it could be exfiltrated and used to sign whatever _you_ (not necessarily the client) want.

Comment: Are you using crypto/other libraries from a CDN? Very unlikely but untrusted code could be used to steal the private key.

Comment: Are you familiar with XSS?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, the way I read it, they're thinking of having the user enter the key, then save the value to a variable without doing a POST or an AJAX request... but I, too, am wondering what the actual use case here is. ml888: If it's just for identification or authentication, or data integrity, then there are user friendly ways that are just as secure. If it's for non-repudiation or confidentiality, then keep in mind that the browser itself offers no guarantees (plugins and extensions can usually execute arbitrary JS on every page a user visits).

Comment: @Ghedipunk - save the key to a variable with the user _assuming_ there is no POST or AJAX request.  That is, what happens if I, as a client, argue that the server **maliciously** stole my key and signed data, because they sent me the code in the first place.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for all the responses, so this app is going to be interacting with a backend, but the front-end is going to be open source.. and ideally, the key provably** doesn't leave the front end. Transactions & messages are signed, and data is encrypted all on the front end before being sent back.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It's meant to interact with the Ethereum (or another smart contract compatible crypto), so it's not about transmission, https is just fine, just would like everything to be signed front-end the way the standard is and want to make sure if it's contacting a server (or multiple servers) it's safe?

Comment: @multithr3at3d I'll vet any 3rd party JS libs I include.

Comment: @Ghedipunk the app can be compiled from source and interact with a backend

Comment: @ConorMancone I have looked into a little but that's why I'm asking, I don't totally understand the vulnerability. If all the JS code can be compiled from source (when I say compiled btw I'm talking in terms of TypeScript to JS like in Angular or whatever framework), then can anyone else steal the private key from wherever it is in memory by accessing the JS?

Comment: The problem is that with a browser front-end, the browser doesn't provide a good way to ensure that what is served is the version that was reviewed, if you turn out to be malicious later (this is different from subresource integrity, which is meant to protect against malicious third parties).  You could post an open source version, but actually serve something else at any point, potentially dynamically (because JS can modify itself, fun times).  I don't know that I'd ever trust a web client for a cryptocurrency.

Comment: @ml888 - to address Conor's point - "compiled" (whether in the traditional sense or the web framework sense) is not a good defense against memory scanning thieves.  Javascript just makes it easier by not being as opaque.  The better defense is to prevent another process from accessing your process' memory/data. XSS is essentially just a way to inject a bit of runnable code into your application's process.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using the [Web Cryptography API](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/).  Then, you can store the user's private key in the [CryptoKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKey) object, with the .extractable property set to false.  This way the private key can only be used for decrypting and/or signing messages within the browser - but can not be read (even by client-side scripting in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into [this](https://pomcor.com/2017/06/02/keys-in-browser/) blog post and corresponding presentation by Pomcor. Storing the key in the browser *does* have security vulnerabilities, in particular malware and physical takeover attacks. That said, there isn't currently a great way to avoid this. Ideally, the private key could be stored in the device hardware, but browsers don't expose access to this today. As @mti2935 notes, Web Cryptography is your best bet today.